# Autoencoders linear latent space

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

According to "Linear interpolation in latent space" in https://hackernoon.com/latent-space-visualization-deep-learning-bits-2-bd09a46920df and others, the latent space representation of an autoencoder is linear in that if I average out two representations and propogate back to input space, I will get a real looking object with the features of the two.

What proof is there to show the space is indeed linear? What is the intution behind in?[image]

Comment: 1) What do you mean by the latent space representation being linear? Linear with respect to what? 2) "What proof is there to show the space is indeed latent?" It's latent by definition. Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable) will help?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am already familar with its contents. Linear with respect to representations. If I were to take raw pixels of two digits and average, I would not get an image that is a digit. However, If I were to average the latent space representations then this corrospond to a image of a digit. Sorry, I meant to ask What proof is there to show the space is indeed linear?

Answer (score 2):

> the latent space representation of an autoencoder is linear in that
>   if I average out two representations and propogate back to input
>   space, I will get a real looking object with the features of the two.

That doesn't make the latent space "linear", and I've never heard the word linear used in that way. There's no official term for this property of latent spaces we want to describe but maybe we can use the word "interpolable" for now.

Let's see what some other people have to say about what makes an interpolable latent space:

Bojanowski et al. in Optimizing the Latent Space of Generative Networks say:

> First, the generator translates linear interpolations in the [latent]
>   space into semantic interpolations in the image space. In other words,
>   a linear interpolation in the [latent] space will generate a smooth
>   interpolation of visually-appealing images

Now back to your question:

> What proof is there to show the space is indeed linear? What is the
>   intution behind in?

Since "smooth" and "visually-appealing" are not mathematically well-defined (at least not as used by Bojanowski), "interpolable" is not a well-defined mathematical concept, so there cannot be any proof.

Comment: Thanks. I see, then how would one justify them being interpolable except for basic examples? I was learning about manifold learning in NN's and wanted to understand this perspective. I understand NN's try to disentagle features and their projections on to their latent space can be viewed as a type of co-ordinate system of this manifold. There is a section called "Latent space arithmetics" in my link which says "For example with faces, man with glasses - man without glasses + woman without glasses = woman with glasses." How are these justified more rigourously/intutively?

Comment: this may be disappointing -- but in short, there is no rigorous justification afaik.